# Entity Framework table-per-type: 1:0...* FK relationship with a derived class - is FK of base class or derived class?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, table-per-type

I have a class `Tenant` which is of the abstract type `UserProfile`. I'm using the table-per-type inheritance approach. A tenant can represent a group of tenants. A `TenantGroupMember` is one of such a group. So, 1 `Tenant` can have zero or many `TenantGroupMember`s.

How is this association represented using the table-per-type approach? They way I've approached it is as follows:

```
[Table("TenantGroupMember")]
public class TenantGroupMember
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TenantGroupMemberId { get; set; }

    // 1:many with Tenant - base UserProfile
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
}

[Table("Tenant")]
public class Tenant : UserProfile
{
    public string TenantAge { get; set; }
    public string PersonalDescription { get; set; }

    // 1:many with TenantGroupMember
    public virtual ICollection<TenantGroupMember> TenantGroupMembers { get; set; }
}
```

Am I correct in making the FK in `TenantGroupMember` from `UserProfile`? Because of the `ICollection TenantGroupMembers` is in `Tenant`, will EF know that a `TenantGroupMember` can only be associated with a `Tenant`, and any not any other derived classes of `UserProfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. However, you have to explicitly declare the `TenantGroupMember.UserProfileId` property as foreign key of the relationship. EF won't detect this by convention and would treat it as ordinary scalar property and create another FK column in the database. You can do it with data annotations...

```
[ForeignKey("UserProfileId")]
public virtual ICollection<TenantGroupMember> TenantGroupMembers { get; set; }
```

...or with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
    .HasMany(t => t.TenantGroupMembers)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(tgm => tgm.UserProfileId);
```

The relationship will have the `Tenant` table in the database as principal/primary key table, not the `UserProfile` table.

Comment: When I try to add a migration I'm getting this error from package manager console "The foreign key component 'UserId' is not a declared property on type 'Tenant'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property." Tenant doesn't explicitly have UserId, but it inherits it from UserProfile. I'm creating associations with Fluent API, any ideas?

Comment: Hi, sorry for waking up an old question, but I'd rather check before posting a new question. I'm working in a project implementing TPT, and we're facing the same problem as you mention in your question. Did Slaurna's answer solve your problem or did you have to do something more to solve it?